# Tesseract-OCR to batch files in all subfolders, Windows cmd?

Tags: batch-file, tesseract

I am trying to use Tesseract-OCR to read and OCR all .png files, not only in current folder, (as there is answer for that) but also in **all subfolders**.
This works for folder:

```
for %%A in ("C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\temp\*.png") do C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe "%%~fA" "%%~dpnxA"
```

I tried with this to go through all subfolders that I have in "temp" folder:

```
(for /r %%a in (*.png) do C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe "%%~nxa" "%%~dpnxA")
```

but I got this errors for every file:

```
C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\temp>C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe "01.png" "%~dpnxA"
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.1.0-elag2019 with Leptonica
Error, cannot read input file 01.png: No such file or directory
Error during processing.
```

It is obvious that the script finds all files in all of the subfolders, but then it cant read then for some reason?

Also, this script works for one folder, but when I try to use with /r it doesnt go  through all subfolders:

```
:Start
   @Echo off
   Set _SourcePath=C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\temp\*.png
   Set _OutputPath=C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\temp\
   Set _Tesseract="C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
:Convert
   For %%A in (%_SourcePath%) Do Echo Converting %%A...&%_Tesseract% %%A %_OutputPath%%%~nA 
:End   
   Set "_SourcePath="
   Set "_OutputPath="
   Set "_Tesseract="
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this sort of thing is what you're looking for:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "_SourcePath=%LocalAppData%\Tesseract-OCR\temp"
Set "_SourceMask=*.png"
Set "_OutputPath=%LocalAppData%\Tesseract-OCR\temp"
Set "_TesserFile=%LocalAppData%\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

For /F "Delims=" %%A In (
    '""%__AppDir__%where.exe" /R "%_SourcePath%" "%_SourceMask%" 2>Nul"'
) Do Echo Converting %%A...& "%_TesserFile%" "%%A" "%_OutputPath%\%%~nA"
```

Note, this assumes that [tesseract](/questions/tagged/tesseract) allows for specifying the output directory and accepts doublequoted strings etc. It also assumes that you intend for all output files to be placed in `%_OutputPath%`.

If you wanted them to be placed along side their respective `.png`'s then perhaps this will do it:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "_SourcePath=%LocalAppData%\Tesseract-OCR\temp"
Set "_SourceMask=*.png"
Set "_TesserFile=%LocalAppData%\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

For /F "Delims=" %%A In (
    '""%__AppDir__%where.exe" /R "%_SourcePath%" "%_SourceMask%" 2>Nul"'
) Do Echo Converting %%A...& "%_TesserFile%" "%%A" "%%~nA"
```

Comment: I tested, it works perfectly! Second script makes the same result, files are all in temp folder. Maybe, as you mention, Tesseract don't allows doublequoted strings.